# Grep command for find single equal operator in php files

Tags: linux, grep

I want search **misused php if statements** with grep command in Linux /var/www directory .

```
//Misused--- i want to find only it
if($a=1){ echo "x"; }

//Correct
if($a==1){ echo "x"; }
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far, what were the results? :)

Comment: Sorry, I could not create any useful examples. I can only search plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -E '\bif *\( *\$[^=]+*\b=\b[^=]+\)' file
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Thank you but it found   if($a!=1)  .  Now i try to understand your command. I will work about it.